# flashbuilder 4.6 / flex - how to use if then to check toggleswitch value

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have an app Im building with that I want to have a toggleswitch control whether or not a function STOPS running or Whether it should RESTART.

how to I set this up?  I've tried

```
if (toggleswitch1.thumbPosition = 0) {
    trace("The function should STOP");              
} else {
trace("The function should RESTART");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a [ToggleSwitch](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/ToggleSwitch.html); you can just use the [selected](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/ToggleSwitch.html#selected) property to determine the state of the button.

```
if (toggleswitch1.selected == false) {
    trace("The function should STOP");              
} else {
trace("The function should RESTART");
}
```

Also, as a critique of your code; this line `toggleswitch1.thumbPosition = 0` is an assignment and will always return true.  If you want to check for equality be sure to use the double equal sign '==' instead of the single equal sign '='.